# Dovid and Avigail

Tags: king-david

When Dovid Hamelech was by the house of Naval, he stated that he will not leave over so much as a dog of Naval's, and that's when Avigail convinced him not to do anything to Naval and rather Hashem will deal with such matters. What's amazing is that their future son, the son of Dovid and Avigail, was named Kileiv (כלב)! Perhaps they were commemorating that Hashem (through Avigail's mussar) prevented Dovid from doing anything bad against Naval. Do any commentaries touch on this?

Comment: Reuben, [Welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887)! Our Q&A model of sharing curiosity and knowledge is different than the model on more free-form fora. We start with question posts that express a clear request for information. This post asks for opinion rather than information, so I'm putting it on hold. If there is some aspect of this topic that you don't yet know and want this community to provide, please [edit] to make your post reflect that.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Now that it's fixed the question should be re-opened.

Comment: Did the verse actually say "not a *kelev*"? Or a *mashtin b'kir*? (I Samuel 25:22.) Be careful not to make up Hebrew based on what you were taught, or read in English. כֹּה-יַעֲשֶׂה אֱלֹהִים לְאֹיְבֵי דָוִד, וְכֹה יֹסִיף:  אִם-אַשְׁאִיר מִכָּל-אֲשֶׁר-לוֹ עַד-הַבֹּקֶר, מַשְׁתִּין בְּקִיר

Comment: @Shalom, yes, the verse explicitly states that nothing will be left, not even a "Mashtin B'Kir", which means a dog.

Comment: @ReubenBakst that is one interpretation, but not the only one. You're suggesting that they named their kid something that, if you changed all the vowels, would be something that is one possible meaning of something David had said earlier (vs. a corruption of *Kalev*, a known name of a Judean leader) ... that is not exactly 1+1=2. Could be ... could be not ...

Comment: @Shalom Thanks but I just want to clarify the mashtin bkir was very specifically a dog according to almost all commentators . You have to remember that Avigail prevented David from doing a major sin, as since he wasn't a known king, as it was done in secrecy, he wasn't allowed to kill somebody fo rebelling, and that's what Avigail told him him s she saved him from doing a major sin. So therefore, it makes perfect sense that they would commemorate her and Hashem savings him from doing a major sin